# How can I pass multiple variables to a JavaScript function in HTML / PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to call a javascript function from php through embedded html.

This is my function.

```
<script> 
    // THIS JAVASCRIPT REDIRECTS TO EDITUSER.PHP AND PASSES USERID VALUE.
    function startMaint(mo, yr){        
        window.location = "startmaintenance.php?mo=" + mo + "yr=" + yr;
    }   
</script>
```

this is where i call my function.

```
<form method="POST" action="home.php">

                <select  name="monthselect">

                    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Month: </option>

                    <?PHP
                        echo"<option value=01>January</option>";
                        echo"<option value=02>February</option>";
                        echo"<option value=03>March</option>";
                        echo"<option value=04>April</option>";
                        echo"<option value=05>May</option>";
                        echo"<option value=06>June</option>";
                        echo"<option value=07>July</option>";
                        echo"<option value=08>August</option>";
                        echo"<option value=09>September</option>";
                        echo"<option value=10>October</option>";
                        echo"<option value=11>November</option>";
                        echo"<option value=12>December</option>";

                    ?>

                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <select  name="yearselect">

                    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Year: </option>

                    <?PHP

                        $year = 1920;

                        While($year <= date("Y")){
                            echo"<option value=$year>".$year."</option>";
                            $year++;
                        }


                echo"</select>";


            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='center'>";

                    $strMonth = $_POST['monthselect'];
                    $strYear = $_POST['yearselect'];

                    echo "<input type='button' class='btn' name='start' value='Start' onclick='javascript:startMaint('".$strMonth."','".$strYear."');'>";

                ?>

                </form>
```

The issue that I am having is that my code is not executing when i press the 'Start' button.

I am not sure if the syntax that I am using is correct when i pass the arguments to the function. any help would be appreciated.

if i manually input the values like this:

```
echo "<input type='button' class='btn' name='start' value='Start' onclick='javascript:startMaint(". 1 .",". 1980 .");'>";
```

It works fine. but if i replace the values with variables, the code does not execute...what i want to do is pass the `$strMonth` and `$strYear` values to the function.

Comment: @praneshravi: don't fix code typos like that until you have CONFIRMATION that OP made a typo adding the code here. you just torpedoed the question,b ecause OP explicitly said "not sure if the syntax ... correct".

Comment: I have tried several syntax and i have not been able to produce the desired outcome. I have edited my question to include more information on what i have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is not a even driven programming language and it's a server side programming language so you need to solve your problem using javascript

Solve the issue this way

```
<script>
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",  function(){
  var mo =   document.getElementById('monthselect').value;
  var yr = document.getElementById('yearselect').value;
  window.location = "startmaintenance.php?mo="+mo+"yr="+yr;
});
</script>
```

Html & PHP code

```
<form method="POST" action="home.php">

                <select id="monthselect"  name="monthselect">

                    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Month: </option>

                    <?php
                        echo"<option value=01>January</option>";
                        echo"<option value=02>February</option>";
                        echo"<option value=03>March</option>";
                        echo"<option value=04>April</option>";
                        echo"<option value=05>May</option>";
                        echo"<option value=06>June</option>";
                        echo"<option value=07>July</option>";
                        echo"<option value=08>August</option>";
                        echo"<option value=09>September</option>";
                        echo"<option value=10>October</option>";
                        echo"<option value=11>November</option>";
                        echo"<option value=12>December</option>";

                    ?>

                </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <select id="yearselect"  name="yearselect">

                    <option value="" disabled selected> Select Year: </option>

                    <?php

                        $year = 1920;

                        While($year<= date("Y")){
                            echo"<option value=$year>".$year."</option>";
                            $year++;
                        }
                    ?>

              </select>


            </div>

            <div class='center'>

  <input type='button' id="btn" class='btn' name='start' value='Start' >

                </form>
```

In the Html code i have added three id attribute id="monthselect", id="yearselect", id="btn"

Comment: thank you, what i did was a little different but i got the idea from your modification so i upvoted your answer. I rewrote my startMaint function like so:  function startMaint()
   {
    var mo =   document.getElementById('monthselect').value;
    var yr = document.getElementById('yearselect').value;
    
    window.location = "startmaintenance.php?mo="+mo+"yr="+yr;
   }
   </script>

Comment: and left the onlclick in the html element: <input type="button" id="btn" class="btn" name="start" value="Start" onclick="javascript:startMaint();">

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to assign `window.location.href`.  Multiple parameters are separated by an ampersand "&".  You also forgot a "+" in your string concatenation.

`window.location.href = "startmaintenance.php?mo=" + mo + "&yr=" + yr;`

Comment: Im sorry, i have edited my question, I was doing just as you suggested before and it would still produce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function startMaint(mo, yr){

            window.location.href = "startmaintenance.php?mo="+mo+"& yr="yr;

        }
```

You use ampersand symbol to concatenate parameters being passed via Get method, and you need the href property of the location object for redirection